# Resize Bootstrap Carusel

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I want to resize the width of my bootstrap carousel, it fits the whole page, and I want to decrease the width and place it in the center.

```html
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="2500">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="./img/_L1A3780.jpg" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="./img/CD2A0553.jpg" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="./img/CD2A2515.jpg" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```css
.carousel-item {
  height: 70vh;
  min-height: 350px;
  max-height: 700px;
  background: no-repeat center center scroll;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}


.carousel .carousel-item {
  transition-duration: 1.5s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't seem to be correct,this is a real bootstrap carossel:

```
 <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="ny.jpg" alt="New York">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

then just apply this css:

```
.carousel-inner > .item > img, .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
            width: 500px;
            margin: auto;
        }
```

Comment: I used the carusel with the indicators, but then I decided to delete them, that's why the code looks like this.